# Convert Pandas Dataframe value to float variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, floating-point

I have the following code to sort a python dataframe:

```
test2 = test.drop(['open', 'high', 'low', 'adjclose', 'volume', 'ticker'], axis=1)
```

The result of that is then:

```
                 close
2020-11-26  102.379997
```

Now I would just like to get the value "102.379997" into a float variable, so I can process it further, for example adding +1 etc.

However, I cannot find code to actually do this.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You can access the value in the DataFrame by indexing the value. It depends on the larger context how to best do that. In the case above it seems like `test2.iloc[0,0]` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nabil Daoud for answering this question, the way to do this is as following:

```
test2.iloc[0,0]
```